# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab

iteration(it).NO=length_without_zero(CH);
But i have this error in this line of my matlab code:
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: That must be the most frequent question asked about Matlab on SO. Try typing the title of your question into the Stack Overflow search bar. If you don't find your answer there, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab, indexing is done from one. I'm guessing that iteration is a vector that you storing data in? If you type

```
iteration(0) = 10;
```

Then you will get that error message. My guess is that you come from another programming language where the value of 0 is used to refer to the first element of an array. Are you doing a loop to update the values in iteration? If so, you should do your loops with the it variable starting at 1. Like so;

```
for it = 1 : 10
    iteration(it) = it - 1;
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i resolved it i write it=1; instead of it=0;